# Make Sent folder show email recipient instead of sender

Tags: exchange, stock-email-app

I am new to Nexus 4 and have a problem. My SENT folder in exchange server mail shows the sender (i.e. me) and not the list of person(s) to whom the mail has been sent. Any help?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Or did it just "correct itself"?
The reason I ask is...........the bullshit is starting over AGAIN!!!
Sent folder shows ME as sender! I THINK I already KNOW that, Google!!!